# How can I get LineLegend to pick up my plot's BaseStyle?

Tags: plotting, legending, version-9

The new legends functionality in version 9 really simplifies creating legends, and it automatically picks up the styles of the lines.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Orange], 
   Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Brown]}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]
```

[image: Nice fat lines]

But if there is a `BaseStyle` option to the plot affecting how the lines are plotted, the legend doesn't pick that up. See how the lines in the legend are now skinnier than in the plot.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Brown},  PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]
```

[image: Oh noes! The lines are skinny!]

How can I get `LineLegend` to see the `BaseStyle` of the plot while maintaining the automatic functionality of not having to explicitly specify the colors used in the plot?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't actually tell the `LineLegends` construct what the `BaseStyle` option of the enclosing plot is. But you *can* set the `BaseStyle` option for the `LineLegend` as well. **Do not be fooled by the red text when you type `BaseStyle` inside the `LineLegend`!** This is just another of those cases where things work even though they are not documented and show up in red.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Brown}, 
 PlotLegends ->  LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3]]]
```

Which actually looks like this:

[image]

Produces this, just as required.

[image: yay! fat lines again!]

Answer (score 5):

This bug was fixed in version 10.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteDashing[{5, 6}], PlotStyle -> {Orange, Brown}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]
```

[image]

However, `AbsoluteThickness` does not seem to propagate as a `BaseStyle`. This might have something to do with the new plot themes.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[15], 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]
```

[image]

If you explicitly set `PlotTheme -> None`, the `BaseStyle` works both for the lines and for the legend.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotTheme -> None, 
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]
```

[image]