# BaseStyle ->AbsoluteThickness[somenumber] doesn't work in version 10?

Tags: plotting, version-10

Users of version 9 might be surprised by this outcome:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]]
```

[image]

It seems that `BaseStyle->AbsoluteThickness[whatever]` doesn't work anymore. How can one fix this?

Comment: Why don't you used PlotStyle instead of BaseStyle?

Comment: @Algohi - this is relevant if you want to set a thickness as the default, e.g. in a package, and then let users choose colors without having to re-select the desired default thickness.

Comment: Interesting effect if you try 100 instead of 5...

Answer (score 12):

The issue seems to be that different `PlotThemes` take precedence over certain settings of `BaseStyle`. As noted in the new answer [to this old question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54525/8), `BaseStyle->AbsoluteDashing[{some list}]` works in the default theme because this isn't specified in the theme.

Here is another odd result. If `PlotTheme` is `"Monochrome"` (or `"Scientific"`), the `BaseStyle` setting for `AbsoluteThickness` affects the axes but not the lines.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

To avoid strange results, set `PlotTheme -> None`.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], 
 PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image]

Themes that have the same issue as the default theme include `"Detailed"`, `"Minimal`", `"Web"`, `"Business"` and `"Marketing"` and `"Classic"`.